# Leaflet.js - Which method to be used for adding markers from GeoJson

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I reffered [official example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) provided by Leaflet.js. But things are not clear to me. And I am confuse about which one to use.

Currently, I am using ***pointToLayer*** for drawing markers :

```
L.geoJson(mapGeoJsonData, {  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) { .... } })
```

But there is also another way to do the same thing using ***onEachFeature***:

```
L.geoJson(mapGeoJsonData, {  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) { .... } })
```

So which one to use when ? What are pros and cons of *pointToLayer* and *onEachFeature*.

Answer (score 2):

Ref: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/GeoJSON.js

pointToLayer is only called for Point and MultiPoint and expects you to return a Marker (you use this callback to create custom markers)

onEachFeature is called for all GeoJSON feature types (including Point and MultiPoint) and does not expect you to return anything (you use this callback to bind popups to Points, Lines ...)

Note that you can't draw markers with onEachFeature but you can use pointToLayer to bind popup to Markers

Comment: In actual I am populating some data from feature. This data is added in the html text boxes inside the popup of the marker (as popup content). After all the markers getting plotted, when I click on any of the marker then it shows empty text boxes. So I used to fill them from data in that marker's object on onPopupOpen event. Data is not preserved or state of marker's content is not maintained. This is the reason I thought the method of pointToLayer might be cause of this situation. Is it so ? Is there any better way to make markers with the data which persist in the marker's popup.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand where your problem is. It works fine for me (look at http://franceimage.github.io/leaflet/9/)